# druid kafka ingestion failed when parsing data using javascript

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, druid

I have a specific format of messages in kafka. They are caret ^ separated. Now to parse this using tranquility I am using below parse spec.

```
        "parser" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "parseSpec" : {
              "timestampSpec" : {
                "column" : "datetime",
                "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
              },
              "dimensionsSpec" : {
                "dimensions" : [],
                "dimensionExclusions" : [
                  "datetime"
                ]
              },
              "format" : "javascript",
              "function" : "function(str) { var parts = str.split('^'); return { key1:parts[0],key2:parts[1],key3:parts[2] } }"
            }
          },
```

However, when I insert a line through kafka producer and check tranquility logs. It shows `droppedCount=1`. So it's dropping messages. I checked above javascript function in browser. It works fine. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it supports javascript format.

My experience is Tranquility does not support full set of Druid configs while the document clearly mentioned "`spec` - a Druid ingestion spec with no ioConfig", and link to Druid config document.  I spent so much time on non-working feature.  I even ran it in debugger stepping thru the code to be sure.

I suggest [Kafka extension](http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html) recently added to Druid.  You do not need Tranquility. I believe all the formats that Druid supports would work with this method.  Please try.

Tranquility hasn't been updated for a long time.   I suggest moving on to the native Kafka ingestion.